# MVC invalid URL parameter

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I have small experience with ASP and Javascript.

I'm working on a ASP.NET MVC5 project and I'm having a problem with Ajax Call to a method
The Jax call go like this :

```js
        $.ajax({
            data: { 'param1': param1Id, 'Param2': param2Id},
            datatype: "json",
            type: "GET",
            url: "../PartSelector/SearchPart",
            cache: false,
            success: function(data) {
                $('#SearchPart').html(data);
            }

        });
```

But I keep getting the error
HTTP404: INTROUVABLE - Le serveur n’a rien trouvé correspondant à l’URI (Uniform Resource Identifier) demandé.
(XHR)GET - http://localhost:10473/Locator/PartSelector/SearchPart?param1=CR00061752&param2=6101&_=1498495699141

My controler look good

```
public ActionResult SearchPart(string param1, string param2)
{

}
```

But when I take a look at the URL a strange parameter is added: "&_=1498495699141" I don't know where this parameter came from.

Can someone help?
Thanks

Hugo

Comment: `&_=1498495699141` comes from `cache: false`. It's harmless.

Comment: Add part of code where is shown how you bind you controller and actions to URLs

Comment: That parameter is not the problem. Either your controller is not allowing a GET operation (is it defined as HttpPost?) or the url is not correct

Comment: Is the Ajax call should be of type "POST" and the method controler wear the [HttpPost] attribute?

Comment: @Sparrow: I don't understand what you meen?

Comment: From the Post URL : http://localhost:10473/Locator/PartSelector/SearchPart?param1=CR00061752&param2=6101&_=1498495699141. How to describ it. http://WebSite/Controler/Method. I'm suspecting a invalid URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finaly been able to make it work:
from the Ajax URL call I needed to change;

```
url: "../PartSelector/SearchPart",
```

to

```
url: "../SearchPart",
```

And I can't understand why.

I guess that it have something to do with the fact that the Method of the call Ajax is not in the same controler has the controler page.

Answer (score 0):

Like what Sparrow said, you need to check if you have [HttpPost] above your controller action. If it's there, then the ajax is not being allowed by the controller since it's of type 'GET'.

Other than that it looks fine to me. Open up the debugger in your browser -> go to Network tab -> click on your action event that causes the ajax call -> look back at the debugger and click on the most recent event (the ajax call) -> go to Network tab -> read off what your 'params' and your 'response' says, then I think I'll be able to help you.